# Can You Grant Admin Access to an Azure Application through PowerShell

Tags: azure, adal

Is there a way to grant administrative consent to an application just using PowerShell?  Imagine you have done Connect-MsolService and provided credentials of an account that is a tenant admin; is there any way to then provide tenant-wide consent based on application client ID?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, do you mean granting the application the ability to access the directory as an admin?

If that is the case, you can do this:

```
# Using the Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell
#
# Connect to the tenant to modify
Connect-MsolService # => login

# Get Service Principal to add the role to
$servicePrincipal = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName Principal.Name

# Get role object ID
# Alternatively, you can list all the roles (in order to get a different role name) using just `Get-MsolRole`
$roleId = (Get-MsolRole -RoleName "Directory Readers").ObjectId

# Add role to service principal
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $roleId -RoleMemberObjectId     $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal

# Check our work
Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $roleId # => should include Principal.Name in list
```

From here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f12c15b7-e2cc-4056-8f0c-1dbfceaeec24/error-adding-service-principal-to-role-this-role-does-not-exist-check-the-name-and-try-again?forum=WindowsAzureAD&prof=required

Consenting to the permissions requested by an application (through its RequiredResourceAccess) can only be done via ADAL during the authorization process.

Comment: Thanks Yi.  Unfortunately it's not a need to add the application to a role, the need is to do the actual consent to an app that you normally do through the browser (i.e. when you do a redirect for an authorization code and include the prompt=admin_consent to the query string.  In this case I have a logged in user in PowerShell that is a tenant admin so I want them to be able to do this same thing, only obviously not in a browser.  Is there possibly some kind of POST direct to the Graph API that could solve this?